# How to convert danish currency to digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have currency like `3.477,60 kr` and i want to use this currenty in js code to add extra price calculation logic. and i have used below code to format it but it give `NaN` in alert.

```
 var currency = "3.477,60 kr";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/(\..*)\./g,'$1'));

alert(number);
```

i want output like `3477.60`
can any one please guide me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
var currency = "3.477,60 kr";
var number = currency.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\,/g, '.').replace(/ kr/g,'');


alert(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```js
var currency = "3.477,60 kr";
var value = currency.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\,/g, '.').split(' ')[0]
console.log(value);
```